# Transforming text to uppercase interferes with the layout

Tags: html, dom, styles, css

I have a link that I'm attempting to style with `text-transform: uppercase`.

When I apply this style half of the link (the 2nd word) breaks to the next line.

What implications (other than case) does text transform have on an element? I've checked 'computed styles' in various browser and nothing else appears to change.

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools :  text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-transform)

Depending on your font, an uppercase letter can be drastically wider than it's lowercase counterpart.
It's not a property of text-transform, it's just standard font-rendering.

If it's appropriate on your project you can look at forcing white-space to behave as you want.

Comment: It’s just misleading to cite w3schools, see http://w3fools.com, and doubly pointless since the issue really has nothing to with CSS really – uppercase letters just tend to be wider than lowercase letters.